# Location of a row with error as a decorator

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen a few other answers on Stackoverflow on how to find the location of a pandas row with an error.

I want to transform this function into a decorator so I can put it on my functions inside a class.
It would make trouble shooting much easier and then I can reuse the function over and over again.

Here is some sample data for `test.txt`

```
2021-07-30 13:29:45, this, is, my test log
2021-07-30 13:29:57, foo, bar, ham spam and eggs
2021-07-30 13:30:45, cheesy, eggs, with, foo bar
FAKE_ERROR_FOR_TESTING, this, is, to break the code
```

This is the decorator and some cleaning code I attempted to write:

```
import pandas as pd


def row_error_number(func):
    """
    row error number returns the rows where an error occurred.
    """
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        for i, item in enumerate(*args):
            try:
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except ValueError:
                print('ERROR at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, item))
        return value
    return wrapper_decorator


@row_error_number
def parse_log(log_file: str, N: int = 100):
    """parse_log summary."""
    with open(log_file) as myfile:
        head = [next(myfile, None) for x in range(N)]
    df = pd.Series(head)
    df = df.str.split(",", n=3, expand=True)  # expand log into new columns
    df = df.rename(columns={0: "time_stamp"})
    df['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_stamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = parse_log(log_file="test.txt", N=100)
    print(df.head())
```

The issue is that I'm not sure how to pass the df back into the enumerate function as an iterable.

```
TypeError: enumerate() missing required argument 'iterable' (pos 1)
```

I want the decorator to be reusable so it will tell me what rows are wrong. A way to limit the number of error rows that it prints out would be really helpful too.

Comment: Your decorator expects a function it call on every element of some iterable; you are decorating a function only takes a file name as an argument. The two are not compatible at all.

Comment: Thanks chepner for your comment. I know they are not compatible, thats what I'm asking help for on how to figure out.

Comment: Do you want something like `head = list(row_error_number(islice(myfile, N)))`? (`islice` being imported from the `itertools` module, to get only the first `N` lines for `myfile`.)